# group html table rows with enclosing tag

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I want to be able to access a subgroup of rows in a html table using a common property assigned to them – let's say I want a pair of rows to disappear using javascript. If it had worked, enclosing those rows with a div and assigning that div to a class would been perfect.

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <div class="hideme_sometimes">
      <tr>...</tr>
      <tr>...</tr>
    </div>
    <tr>...</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){$("div.hideme_sometimes").hide();}); 
</script>
```

But obviously you can't put parts of a table inside a div, or a span. Is there some other way of grouping `<tr>` elements to the same effect?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can have multiple [tbody](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody) elements which can surround the rows.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.setAttribute("hidden", true)
    document.querySelectorAll("tbody")[1].removeAttribute("hidden")
});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>foo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody hidden>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button">more</button>
```

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for. Thank you. the `<tbody>` elements can the be given id's or classes and accessed by that.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put a `class` on them, and query by class, so

```
$("div.hideme_sometimes").hide();
```

becomes

```
$("tr.hideme_sometimes").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about assigning `class=hideme_sometimes` to each of the rows and calling `$(".hideme_sometimes").hide();`

Comment: In this particular example it would work, but my real (and more complicated) problem is more about being able to access groups of `<tr>`elements collectively, and each group in an arbitrary manner. Therefore, @epascarello's answer is best for my purposes. Sorry if I stated my problem a bit unclearly.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it may be convenient to use [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Rows in the same group could be assigned the same index, for example:

```html
<tr data-group-index="0">...</tr>
```

and you can select a group of rows using CSS attribute selectors, for example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('tr[data-group-index="0"]')
```

Once you  have selected a `<tr>` element (as `row`), you can either read (and write) the attribute value using `getAttribute` (and `setAttribute`) or you can use the [dataset property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```js
row.getAttribute('data-group-index') === row.dataset.groupIndex
```